# How can I create and access test cases in Team Foundation Server using visual C# console

Tags: c#, tfs

I am working with VS C# to manipulate test cases, create projects, and anything else that's beneficial to my testing in TFS. However, there are not any solid examples out there. The API that is on the Microsoft Developer site is just not helpful to me (could be my lack of experience in coding in VS), but I am becoming frustrated. Any progress that I make takes several days ( ... really hit and miss). Can someone direct me to a consolidated resource for using the team foundation server object model to implement features programmatically: WebSites, Books, etc...? Thanks!!! Below is what appears to be very straightforward code to create a Default collection/Project and write a test case in VSO TFS with C# (It continues to fail):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;



namespace myProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string serverurl = "http://localhost:8080/tfs";
            string project = "Beta1";
            ITestManagementTeamProject proj = GetProject(serverurl, project);

            ITestCase tc = proj.TestCases.Create();
            tc.Title = "Test";
            tc.Save();

            Console.WriteLine("TC: {0}", tc.Id);
        }


        static ITestManagementTeamProject GetProject(string serverUrl,
            string project)
        {
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullQualifiedUriForName(serverUrl));
            ITestManagementService tms = tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>();

            return tms.GetTeamProject(project);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For online references, I would heartily recommend Shai Raiten's blog:  http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2011/05/18/tfs-api-index-parts-1-to-37/ you might also find some of my posts useful: http://pmichaels.net/2016/11/30/programmatically-creating-a-test-case-for-a-work-item-using-the-tfs-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serverul "http://localhost:8080/tfs" in your code snippet means you are handling with on-premise TFS. But in your description, you want to create a test case work item in Visual Studio Online.

For Visual Studio Online api, you can refer to Visual Studio Online REST API at website:

> https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview

For deal with on-premise TFS programmatically, you can refer to blogs below:

> http://joymonscode.blogspot.in/2009/05/beginning-tfs-programming.html
>   http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/18/tfs-2010-sdk-connecting-to-tfs-2010-programmaticallyndashpart-1.aspx